# .ejs formatting in VSCode

Tags: ejs, visual-studio-code, hexo

This is my problem - its unreadable

[image: unreadable code]

In order to get .ejs working in general, I've so far added the following. I also have format on save and prettier. I'm looking for proposals to get better formatting of this so that I can read it.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ejs": "html",
    "*.css": "postcss"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "postcss": "css",
    "ejs": "html"
},
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "postcss": "css",
    "ejs": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that's an old question, but working with .ejs in VSCode is still a problem. But I found the solution (for `?` delimeter)

1. Install `EJS language support` plugin
2. Now you have ejs support, highlighting, and snippets, but some tags like

```html
<? for( let item of array ) { ?>
(some data)
<? } ?>
```

are formatted incorrectly (at least with default html formatter).

3. To fix this, you can try set custom delimeter to '?' `ejs.delimeter = '?'`. Now you have correct indentation with `<? ... ?>` tags.
4. To use the snippets with our custom delimeter, you need to edit extension snippets (or add your own): install `Snippets Ranger` plugin, then find needed extension and edit its file. The `Snippets Ranger` is very handy tool.

I hope I helped somebody to setup VSCode for .ejs files

Comment: reinstalled VSCode, used my own solution again, hah)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using 
**[EJS language support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support)**
which is according to them

> Syntax highlighting for EJS, Javascript, and HTML tags. Includes
>   javascript autocompletion.

and if you are interested in a Linter you should check out

**[EJS-Lint](https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint)**
which according to them

> EJS-Lint parses scriptlet tags (<%, %>, <%_, _%>, and -%>). It ignores
>   all other tags (i.e. <%=).
>
> Note: This linter does not attempt to check for unclosed EJS tags, so
>   if you get an error Unexpected token with a line number that doesn't
>   contain any scriptlets, you most likely forgot to close a tag earlier.
>
> It also is set up to handle old-style includes (<% include filename
>   %>) by ignoring them. It does not lint included files regardless of
>   the method of inclusion.
>
> It can work with custom delimiters, just pass it in the options (if
>   using the API) or pass the --delimiter (-d) flag on the CLI.